# market, grocery shop, python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

can you please give me some hint how can i store the foods that will show on output of the last code, should i use list for storing and or should i use dictionary and also have to store the amount and the price of it of it. thank you

Once the customer chooses a product to
add to the basket, the program will ask for the amount.

```
inventory={'asparagus':[10,5],'broccoli':[15,6],'carrots':[18,7],
'apples':[20,5],'banana':[10,8],'berries':[30,3],
'eggs':[50,2],'mixed fruit juice':[0,8],'fish sticks':[25,12],
'ice cream':[32,6], 'apple juice':[40,7], 'orange juice':[30,8],
'grape juice':[10,9]}
menu_list=["1. Search for the product", "2. See the basket","3. Check Out","4. Logout","5. Exit"]

def return_to_main():
    digit = 1
    for i in menu_list:
        print i

    main_menu=raw_input("Please choose one of the following services")
    if main_menu=="1":
        select=raw_input("Search for the product")
        for food in inventory:
            if select in food:
                print str(digit)+".",food,inventory[food][0]
                digit+=1
return_to_main()
```

Comment: The output you are expecting is unclear.

Comment: @Alex, the last output for now show 1. carrots 18
2. grape juice 10
3. broccoli 15
4. ice cream 32
5. orange juice 30
6. asparagus 10
7. mixed fruit juice 0
8. berries 30
and i have to select one of these to store in the basket but i have no idea, by the way the output differs when you search for something else